# Adding new user to shared git respository doesn't work

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins-plugins

I've set up a shared git respository on my server. This is quite handy, because now my team and I can work well together. Now I wanted to integrate Jenkins to our tools. When I set up the Jenkins Plugin for Git I always get the error message:

```
  Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h jenkins@.......at:nomocom.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
  stdout: 
  stderr: Host key verification failed. 
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Now I thought maybe there is a problem with the jenkins user and I added a new user called John. But with this user I get the same error message. To add John I run the following command:

```
  $ sudo useradd -G developers -d /home/john -m -s /bin/bash john
```

To initialize the git repo I did the following things:

```
  $ git init --bare --shared=group
  $ sudo chgrp -R developers .
```

So basically I want to grant permissions to all users in the group developers. This worked great for users I created before the git repo, but new users are refused to connect to the repo.

I'm running git version 1.8.2.3 under Ubuntu 10.04 and jenkins in version 1.516 (I installed Jenkins via apt-get)

[image: Log of console] 
As you can see it works perfectly for users georgko and paul, but not for users jenkins and john. All of the users are in the developers group.

To setup the git repo I followed the following tutorial: [How To Create a Remote Shared Git Repository](http://kovshenin.com/2011/howto-remote-shared-git-repository/)

I am a real git and linux n00b so I'm not sure what to do to solve this issue. What am I missing? Why isn't it working for new users? How can I "debug" this issue?

Thank you in advance for all your tipps,
Tschoartschi
btw: i blurred the address of my server, because I'm not sure if my server is secure enough to publish the address public.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood something wrong with the paths. I did the linking like it was described in the tutorial [Link](http://kovshenin.com/2011/howto-remote-shared-git-repository/) and this solved the issue. What I did exactly was only the following command:

```
  $sudo ln -s /var/www/gitrepos/nomocom.git/ /home/jenkins/
```